# Why I can't assign string::back to string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I write a simple program:
Get last character of string1 and assign it to string2.
It's like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string s1 = "abc!";
    std::string s2 = s1.back();
    std::cout << s1;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get a compile error:

```
conversion from ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type {aka char}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ requested
```

I don't know this error exactly means.
It's seems like some type conversion error occur.
But the return value of string::back should be char, right?

Why I can't assign it to another string?
And how I can give last character of s1 to s2?

Comment: A string is a sequence of characters. One character is not a string.

Comment: ^ That exactly explains the reason for the error message.

Comment: On a side note, `std::string s1 = something;` is not assignment, but [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `std::string` does not have an implicit [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which takes just a single character parameter, that's why conversion from `char` to `std::string` fails. Instead you can use:

```
// 1. Constructor with length + char
std::string s2(1, s1.back());

// 2. Constructor which takes an std::initializer_list<char>
std::string s2{s1.back()};
```

Comment: It does, however, have a `operator=` that takes a single `char`: `std::string s2; s2 = s1.back();`

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it would explain, that OP is not doing assignment, but [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). This would lead to the statement, that only implicit constructors are considered.

Answer (score 1):

A string is a **collection of characters**, the back of a string is a *character* (i.e., just an element of the collection), not a string.

You can achieve what you want by using the following constructor overload of `std::string`:

```
std::string s2(1, s1.back());
```

That is, construct `s2` as a one-character-length string with the value `s1.back()`.

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are trying to create a new string s2 out of the last character of string s1.
You can achieve that using the solution below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "abc!";
    std::string s2;
    s2 = s1.back();
    std::cout << s1;
    std::cout << s2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or using `operator=` instead: `std::string s2; s2 = s1.back();`